# Adding existing database into postgreSQL 9.0

Tags: database, postgresql

I've installed postgrSQL 9.0 successfully and I have separate database file (`database.backup`). Now I need to add this database into postgreSQL. I am new to this postgreSLQ. I would be much appreciated if anyone please be so kind enough to explain how to do such a thing.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @TimurSadykov I think you chose the wrong link there, it's completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: i would prefer to use 'completely unrelated' term to question about potatoes for example... :) but anyway,  yes, I missed .backup in the question. So it looks worse than before :) a question without any research on the topic.

Comment: seem like it was pretty easy to miss .backup :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PgAdmin-III to restore the DB, or use the `pg_restore` command, which does the same thing at the command line.

See [the PgAdmin-III docs](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/restore.html).

I don't use PgAdmin-III, I work from the command line but from memory you need to:

- Connect PgAdmin-III to the DB
- Create a blank database
- Right click on it
- Choose "Restore...."
- Pick the ".backup" file